# How can I use a reference only and make no copies of the object argument in php

Tags: php, object, copy, pass-by-reference, pass-by-value

I have a function that requires information to be passed to it. The information is contained within an object. Therefore I must pass that object as one of the function arguments. The object is very large however, and I would like to reduce the overhead involved in making copies every time it is passed. Here is an example of 
My function Call:

```
1 myFunction($myObject1);
```

and the function:

```
2 function myFunction($myObject2){
3  //do stuff
4 }
```

I understand there is more to it in php than just pass-by-reference vs pass-by-value. Correct me if I am wrong, but I believe on line 1 there is only a reference to the object made, but on line 2 the object is copied. To avoid this copy I have replaced `($myObject2)` with `(&$myObject2)`. I still refer to the object within the function definition as `$myObject2` and everything seems to work. I believe I am now using a reference only and therefore making no copies of the object (which was my goal). Is my thinking correct? If not not why?

Answer (score 0):

In PHP5, "objects" are not values. The value of the variables `$myObject1`, `$myObject2` are object references (i.e. pointers to objects). You cannot get "the object itself"; objects can only be manipulated through these pointers.

Assignment and passing by value only copy values. Since objects are not values, they cannot ever be cloned through assignment, passing, etc. The only way to duplicate an object is to use the `clone` operator.

Putting `&` on a variable makes it pass or assign by reference, instead of by value without the `&`. Passing by reference allows you to modify the variable passed. Since the value of a variable cannot be an object, this has nothing to do with objects.

Comment: so I'm still confused overall, but it seems that this means:
1) adding the `&` does NOTHING AT ALL in this case.
2) passing huge objects back and forth many times will have very low overhead without anything special needing to be done.

Comment: @VoltzRoad: 2 is correct, because you can't pass objects, you only pass (or assign, or deal with) pointers to objects. 1 is not true -- adding `&` makes it pass-by-reference; whereas without the `&` it is pass-by-value.